# Reaction of 3-chloro-2,2-dimethylbutane with sodium ethanolate in EtOH, which mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, solvents

When we let 3-chloro-2,2-dimethylbutane react with sodium ethanolate in EtOH, which reaction do we expect? SN2, E2, E1 or SN1?

I would say it's an SN2 reaction because ethanolate is not that strong of a base, but is that correct? A carbocation would also be stabilized insufficiently, because it's a secondary one, so either E2 or SN2 would be probable, but I don't know if [OEt]- is sufficiently basic to favor the E2 reaction. I would be glad over any tips on this question, thanks in advance.

Comment: How different are ethoxide and hydroxide in basicity? What are the pKa's of their conjugate acids?

Comment: This is a very hindered system so you are not going to get very much SN2. Neo-pentyl halides are very poor electrophiles and this is yet more hindered. E2 is the most likely event.